# Fixing strange artifact when rotating views

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller, screen-rotation

I have an application that is 99.9% portrait.  However there is one screen where we allow landscape so that our users can have more real-estate while writing up a post.  My issue happens when a user decides to go back from our edit screen while in landscape mode to our previous screen that can only display in portrait mode we get the navigation bar cut off:

[image: funky looking navigation bar]

Has anyone seen this before or have any thoughts on how to fix the problem?

**EDIT** Not sure if it's noticeable but what is happening is that the area that is available for the NavigationBar to be drawn in is truncated to the same height as if the view was in landscape mode, and the black bar is the difference between the Portrait NavigationBar height and the Landscape NavigationBar height.

Comment: Where are you handling your orientation change? Are the portrait and landscape layouts in separate views?

Comment: They are 2 separate view controllers.  The one in the image attached is Portrait only, and the other will go landscape for the larger keyboard.

Comment: Sorry, let me clarify the first question: in what method are you handling your orientation change?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using:

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
```

then the original view (landscape) is still present.

Use the:

```
- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation
```

to adjust your view interface.

This is all a guess because you need to give more information about what you are doing, that is the cause of this.

Answer (score 0):

Use the code below to dump the superviews and the subviews of self.view before you rotate, then after the rotation is done, then again when the rotation back to portrait is done. One of the views will not match its original origin, and that will be your problem view. The change in origin may well be due to the struts not being enabled on the top/left.

This happened to me so many times I wrote this UIView category to dump super and subviews.

Usage:

```
[UIView dumpSuperviews:self.view msg:@"Original superviews"];
[UIView dumpSubviews:self.view msg:@"Original subviews"];
```

Code:

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

#import "UIView+Utilities.h"

@interface UIView (Utilities_Private)

+ (void)appendView:(UIView *)v toStr:(NSMutableString *)str;

@end

@implementation UIView (Utilities_Private)

+ (void)appendView:(UIView *)a toStr:(NSMutableString *)str
{
    [str appendFormat:@"  %@: frame=%@ bounds=%@ layerFrame=%@ tag=%d userInteraction=%d alpha=%f hidden=%d\n", 
        NSStringFromClass([a class]),
        NSStringFromCGRect(a.frame),
        NSStringFromCGRect(a.bounds),
        NSStringFromCGRect(a.layer.frame),
        a.tag, 
        a.userInteractionEnabled,
        a.alpha,
        a.isHidden
        ];
}

@end

@implementation UIView (Utilities)

+ (void)dumpSuperviews:(UIView *)v msg:(NSString *)msg
{
    NSMutableString *str = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:256];

    while(v) {
        [self appendView:v toStr:str];
        v = v.superview;
    }
    [str appendString:@"\n"];

    NSLog(@"%@:\n%@", msg, str);
}

+ (void)dumpSubviews:(UIView *)v msg:(NSString *)msg
{
    NSMutableString *str = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:256];

    if(v) [self appendView:v toStr:str];
    for(UIView *a in v.subviews) {
        [self appendView:a toStr:str];
    }
    [str appendString:@"\n"];

    NSLog(@"%@:\n%@", msg, str);
}

@end
```